# 'and is ...' or 'and it is ...'?

Tags: grammar

Which of the two sentences is more proper/correct? Are both of them acceptable?

> This new course is part of the new Masters degree, and is only needed if the Masters degree is approved

or

> This new course is part of the new Masters degree, and **it** is only needed if the Masters degree is approved

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. The second sentence puts more emphasis on the subject.

Comment: Stylistically I would drop the comma in the first because it further separates the verb from its subject. Grammatical either way.

Comment: ", and is" or "and, is" ?? @Unrelated